# Don't remember my login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a Laravel project and I'm currently trying to implement a method for users logging in.  I read on the documentation that `Auth::attempt()`'s second param is a `bool $remember` which defaults to `false`.

I have no settings for the second param so I assume when exiting my browser completely, I should be logged out.  This is not the case.  I seem to have the same functionality regardless of my `bool $remember` param's setting of `true` or `false`.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array(
    'email' => Input::get('email'), 
    'password' => Input::get('password'), 
    'status' => 'accepted')))
{
    // ... logged in
}
```

Comment: When you re-enter, are you logged in or are your credentials just remembered in the inputs?

Comment: Is this about the autocomplete in the input field or about the cookie ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `app/config/session.php` and set `lifetime` to 0.

Comment: adding the lifetime to 0 causes token errors, but leaving it at 120 and setting expire_on_close = true fixes it.  thanks for leading me in the right direction, wouldn't have found it without looking there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log a person in for that one request without session/cookie you should use `Auth::once($credentials)` instead of `Auth::attempt($credentials)`